# how to use Log4Net with Autofac in CommonLibrary project

Tags: c#, log4net, autofac

I am using autofac in my web api to register log4net . It is working fine in controller but how can i use same log4net instance for common library project classes in same solution.

I have used below code for registering log4net using autofac in web api.

```
// IOC Container Setup uisng Autofac
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register your Web API controllers.
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.Register(c => LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Object))).As<ILog>();
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
builder.RegisterModule<AMLWebApiModule>();
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
var container = builder.Build();
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

I am using logger as a property in common library project.
  `public ILog logger { get; set; }`

when i tried to log message it is giving below exception.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please advise how can i use log4net in common library project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two approaches to make this work

1) Inject ILog in the class library project
2) Resolve the Ilog object in the class library project

I would go for option 1) and will register all my components in autofac to take full advantage of DI and keep each component independent.

Example Code,

Create a contract for the class library project example

```
public interface Ilibrary
{
    string GetName();
}

public class Library : Ilibrary
{
    private ILog _log;
    public Library(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }
    public string GetName()
    {
        _log.Debug("log message");
        return "test";
    }
}
```

then either create a module in the class library project and register that module in your application start.

```
public class DomainModule : Module
{

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
      {
        base.Load(builder);

        builder.RegisterType<Library>()
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .SingleInstance();
      }
}
```

Or you can directly register too if you have access to the concert implementation just by doing this in your application start.

```
builder.RegisterType<Library>()
.AsImplementedInterfaces()
.SingleInstance();
```

Comment: How to register class against abstract class rather than interface?

Comment: try it just like an interface , i believe it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Logger as a property in your common library project, you can just decorate/annotate that property with [Dependency] attribute. This is called property injection. I am not sure if you have to have to do extra configuration for property injected dependencies in autofac but you can try if not you can search it.